# C# String Comparison

Tags: c#

I am making an application i have to compare two strings for a specific word

for eg

```
string a="abc";
string b="abcController";
```

I have to compare `a` and `b` to match abc

I am using `Equals` or `CompareTo` but these are not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the simplest fashion, you can use [the `Contains` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
var a = "abc";
var b = "abcSOMDH";
var c = b.Contains(a);
```

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and
>   culture-insensitive) comparison. The search begins at the first
>   character position of this string and continues through the last
>   character position.

Comment: Thanks
It worked for me, but how can i apply it for case insensitive, means if a="abc" and b="Abc" it should still match correctly

Comment: You can convert both strings [`ToUpperInvariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx) prior to checking.

Comment: `b.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(a.ToLowerInvariant())`

Comment: I would suggest using the overload for Contains for which you can supply a StringComparer rether that creating a new string with ToUpperInvariant:  bool c = b.Contains(a, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Answer (score 3):

```
string str1 = "abc";
string str2 = "abcController";
if(str2.Contains(str1))
     ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 string a = "abc";
 string b = "abcdefsdfs";
 if (a.Contains(b) || b.Contains(a))
     //DO SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.Contains` method

```
b.Contains(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `Contains` would be `IndexOf`

```
var a = "abc";
var b = "abcSOMDH";
var c = b.IndexOf(a) >= 0; // returns TRUE if b occurs in a
var d = b.IndexOf(a, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // same but case insensitive
```

Description from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of one or more characters, 
or the first occurrence of a string, within this string. The method returns -1 if 
the character or string is not found in this instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick comment on the answers above: it's not a good idea to use ToLowerInvariant() or ToUpperInvariant(). Both of these calls have to create brand new strings, upper or lower case, before comparison.

Instead, use an overload of the Contains() method that accepts an IEqualityComparer, like this:

```
string stringA; stringA.Contains(stringB, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This will do a case-insensitive comparison without allocating memory and copying the strings around.